# how to pushViewController to another view with images in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `scrollview` of `images`, I will like to tab them and will pushed to another view.

once i tab on the image, the whole view should push to another view.

From this View to another view

[image: 1]

Detail view

[image: 2]

Sorry for not asking the question clearly.

my scrollview

```
-(void)pictureScrolling
{
//init scrollview in location on screen
scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 290)];   
scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
//pass image filenames
NSMutableArray *fileNames = nearbyFrog.imageFiles; //[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

//setup the array of uiimageviews
NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView;

//loop through the array imgNames to add file names to imgArray
for (NSString *imageName in fileNames) {

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imgArray addObject:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

CGSize pageSize = scrollview.frame.size; 
NSUInteger page = 0;

for (UIView *viewForScrollView in imgArray) {

    [scrollview addSubview:viewForScrollView];

    viewForScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ +10, 0, pageSize.width -20 , pageSize.height);

    // making use of the scrollView's frame size (pageSize) so we need to;
    // +10 to left offset of image pos (1/2 the gap)
    // -20 for UIImageView's width (to leave 10 gap at left and right)
}
//add scroll view to view
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);

//scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 *viewcount + 20, 290 );
scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =NO;
[scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
scrollview.delegate =self;

//paging function for scrollview
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.pageControl = [[[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 50)] autorelease];
self.pageControl.center = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height-60);
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [fileNames count];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];    

//handle Touch Even
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[imgArray release];
```

}

anybody knows how to do it or can show me a tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Is it right that you have got a scrollview with images in it and if you tap on an image the image should be pushed to the navigationcontroller?

Comment: Your question is not fully clear, answer @thomas 's question, or elaborate it for clearness.

Comment: sorry about it,

edited my question and add in picture for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best way to implement it

1. Create your own Custom UIImageView class. This is required to store an additional property which will help you identify which image for clicked.
2. Create a delegate for that class which is called with the single tap event is raised in the UIImageView
3. Add the Images inside the scrollview using this custom class. The delegate of this class will tell you which image was tapped. You can use this to push a new view controller passing the image details (if necessary).

You can find some sample code in the ThumbImageView class in the scrollviewSuite sample

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm looking at the code now... but i still cannot understand how it works

Comment: Since you are tapping inside a UIImageview, the tap event is captured by the UIImageview. You need to propogate the same to the Viewcontroller which will enable you to make the decision on pushing the next view controller. Hence, you need a delegate on the UIImageview. Since the UIImageview has not got a property to store the name of the Image you need to create a property yourself

Comment: but the UIImageview is the subview of scrollview